# Why the pivots and relative to the eigenvalue in symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In the book, it said, there a quick fast way to test whether the eigenvalue are all positive or not.

Just check the pivot of the symmetric matrix, if x no. of positive pivot, it would have x no.of eigenvalue.

It also mentioned that it should be prove by the

$$A=LDL^T$$

But I can't understand what's the secret behind?

Comment: The magic is provided by the Sylvester's law of inertia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_law_of_inertia

Answer (score 2):

We can express the symmetric matrix $A$ as in $A=QΛQ^T$, and we can also express the upper triangular matrix $u$ of matrix $A$ by elimination matrix E as $u=EA$, and then $uE^T=EAE^T$, where $D = uE^T$ is a diagonal matrix which contains pivots on the diagonal. The same applies $Λ=Q^{-1}A(Q^T)^{-1}$, and $(Q^T)^{-1}=(Q^{-1})^T$ as $(Q^T)(Q^{-1})^T=(Q^{-1}Q)^T=I^T=I$. By Sylvester's law of inertia, the number of positive pivots equal to the number of positive eigenvalues.

Comment: A very nice proof! I wonder how one can prove that the signs of pivots agree with the signs of eigenvalues in the case of a symmetric matrix $A$ which requires row exchanges for LU decomposition?

Comment: @ashpool I don't think this works for the general case $PA = LU$. For example, take $A = [0\,\,1; 1\,\,0]$. This $A$ has pivots 1 and 1, but eigenvalues 1 and -1.