# Is it true that the number of positive eigenvalues of symmetry matrix is equal to the number of positive pivots?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$
\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}{\rm{0}}&{\rm{1}}\\{\rm{1}}&{\rm{0}}\end{array}} \right)
$$
This is a symmetry matrix. And the eigenvalues of this matrix are 1 and -1.

Here is the definition of pivot. If a matrix is in row-echelon form, then the first nonzero entry of each row is called a pivot. So after swapping row1 with row2 the matrix will be in row-echelon form, and the pivots are 1 and 1.

Clearly, in this example, the number of positive eigenvalues is 1, but the number of positive pivots is 2. They are not the same. So I think the conclusion in the title is not true.

However, according to Strang, "Linear Algebra and Applications", 3ed, Theorem 6G, real symmetric matrix have same number of positive, negative and zero eigenvalues and pivots.  Matrix need not be invertible.

Let matrix A be real symmetric matrix and $B=PAP^T$, where P is permutation matrix.  P is applied to swap rows in A such that pivot are in correct row and Gaussian elimination can proceed.  Then $PAP^T=B=LDU=U^TDU$.  L is invertible lower tri-angular matrix.  U is invertible upper tri-angular matrix.  D is diagonal matrix.  If A is singular then at least one diagonal entry in D is 0.  $L=U^T$ because B is symmetric.  By Law of Inertia, D preserve B eigenvalue sign and vice versa.  Also because D is diagonal, its pivot equal its eigenvalue.  Thus for B, sign of pivot equal sign of eigenvalue.  Because all permutation matrix is invertible, by applying Law of Inertia again, B preserve A eigenvalue sign and vice versa.  B and A also have same pivot (A may have pivot in wrong row, thus potentially requiring permutation matrix).  Thus A have same number of positive, negative and zero eigenvalue and pivot.

So what's wrong with my example? Do I misunderstand the definition of pivot? Or the proof above is wrong?

Comment: Whta do you call "pivots" to? The leading terms in each row after reducing the matrix? Then (1) your matrix isn't row-reduced, (2) if it were **as  it is** then it'd have two positive pivots, which contradicts directly what your your title says, (3) Even if the above doesn't bother, multiplying a row by a negative number would change all...

Comment: @DonAntonio (1) I think after swapping row2 with row1 then the matrix becomes row-reduced. The pivots I think are the first non-zero elements in each row. (2)According to [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3621633) what the title says seems right. (3)I agree with your point, and this is why I'm confused.

Comment: You didn't clear much. It is important you explain or define clearly your terms in the body of your question. If it is as I askwed, and it seems to be, then we're done: the statement is false.

Comment: @DonAntonio I put the proof in the body. Could you give me some advice?

Comment: Observe that in the example you gave, swapping rows 1-2 leads to a non-similar matrix, since they have different eigenvalues...! This means that reducing a matrix gives a matrixwhcih is not necessarily similar to the original one...and thus what you want to prove is false.    But theorem LG in Strang is very strange to me: observe that after the theorem he mentions that one can **not** swap rows in $\;A\;$ ...so it's hard what he means and what he calls "pivot matrix" to exactly. Could it be "diagonal matrix" ...??

Answer (score -1):

Same question here, I really doubt that is a mistake caused by Strang. This is my interpretation:
I used your example,
$$
\begin{equation*}
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1  \\
1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}. 
$$

Then follow the proof in the book: $B = PAP^T$ which a permutation matrix
$$
\begin{equation*}
P=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1  \\
1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}. 
$$ is applied to swap rows in A such that pivots are in the correct row.
Definitely, the $A = B = PAP^T$, and there is nothing changed. And see the last comment in this link: [Why the pivots and relative to the eigenvalue in symmetric matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584620/why-the-pivots-and-relative-to-the-eigenvalue-in-symmetric-matrix)

It noted that in Strang's other book 《Introduction to linear Algebra》,  the similar proof is not appropriate for the general case $PA=LU$.